# How to get SAML assertion from OpenAM (using Java)?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, assertion, openam, vcloud-director-rest-api

I'm in the midst of finding some means (preferably through Java code) that will enable me to get the SAML assertion from the IDP (i.e. ForgeRock's OpenAM) for a Service Provider (SP) via SSO Login.

The SP have already been configured to interact with the IDP (e.g. vCloud Director --> OpenAM and vice versa) through a Web Browser (i.e. the user will be automatically redirected to the OpenAM login page upon invoking the vCloud Director login page). However, this process is only applicable through browsers (where redirection is provided) but not outside the browser.

I can't seem to find any means to perform SSO Login (by using the SAML assertion from the IDP for authentication). So far I've come across a dozen of references including the AssertionIDRequestUtil.sendAssertionIDRequestURI function from the OpenAM SSO, still, I'm not sure where to retrieve the AssertionId and SAML EntityId parameters.

Are there other means of getting the SAML assertion? Or maybe other ways to perform SSO Login?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to achieve this would be:

1. perform authentication via REST or ClientSDK
2. use a Java HTTP client to kick off an IdP initiated SAML authentication flow (/openam/idpssoinit?metaAlias=/idp&spEntityID=entityID). When you send this request you need to make sure that:

   - the session id is part of the request as an iPlanetDirectoryPro cookie,
   - session upgrade won't be performed (your authcontext settings at the IdP will have a lower or equal authLevel, than the level the session was created with in the first step)

Comment: Hi there. Thank you for your answer. However, I've looked through some REST services from both OpenAM and vCloud Director but to no avail.

Comment: By the way, the Session Id is refers to the token generated when logging in to OpenAM?

Comment: Also, I'm confused, the `entityID` refers to the SP (i.e. the vCloud Director) base URL right? Thanks so much.

Comment: The REST authentication endpoint can be found at /openam/identity/authenticate , but that is only able to handle username/password combination. If you need something more complicated, then you need to use the ClientSDK for authentication. The entity ID will refer to the SP, you can find the SP's entity ID in the SAML metadata.